# SharePoint 2010 Document Set New Documents Button

Tags: 2010, content-type, document-set

I am implementing a Document Set based case management solution - positioning the case file as a Document Set Content Type then having Document Content Types for documents required within the case file.

I am having difficulty in changing the order of the documents from the New Document button - does anyone have any potential solutions or work arounds? Note - because from the Document Library view I have only the Grant Case File as an option from the New Document button, changing the order from 'Change new button order and default content type' has no effect, nor does the order in which I add Allowed Content Types in Document Set Settings.